# Find the count of a specific keyword in multiple files in a directory

Tags: grep

Say I have a directory `/home/` and within it I have 3 subdirectories `/home/red/`  `/home/blue/`  `/home/green/`

And each subdirectory contains a file each like

`/home/red/file1` `/home/blue/file2`  `/home/green/file3`

Now I want to find how many times `file1`,`file2`, `file3` contains the word "hello" within them.

For example,

```
/home/red/file1 - 23
/home/blue/file2 - 6
/home/green/file3 - 0
```

Now, going to the locations of file and running the grep command is actually very inefficient when this problem scales.

I have tried using this grep command from the `/home/` directory

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'
```

But this is just giving the occurrences rather than the count.

Is there any command through which I can get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search term occurs at maximum once per line, you can use `grep`'s `-c` option to report the count instead of the matching lines. So, the command will be `grep -rc 'search'` (add other options as needed).

If there can be more than one occurrence per line, I'd recommend using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). Note that `rg` recursively searches by default, so you can use something like `rg -co 'search'` from within the home directory (add other options as needed). Add `--hidden` if you need to search hidden files as well. Add `--include-zero` if you want to show files even if they didn't have any match.

Comment: Say the count is one only per line, then what is the command that we should use?

Comment: `grep -rc 'search'` (add other options as needed). Note that `ripgrep` will likely be much faster since it has parallelism and other optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grep` you can use this `find | gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
cd /home
find {red/file1,blue/file2,green/file3} -type f -exec awk '
{c += gsub(/pattern/, "&")} ENDFILE {print FILENAME, "-", c; c=0}' {} +
```